# Issue with Visual Studio array indexers being incorrectly autocompleted in Razor code

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, visual-studio-2022

As the title says, I'm having issue autocompleting index access with lists/arrays (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zENu.jpg) for a gif of the example)

When I type `myArr[0` and finish typing with `]`, it is replaced to `myArr[#if]`.
`myArr[1]` transforms to `myArr[Int128]`, etc.

Is there a way to disable this? (I know that I can press right arrow to avoid this, but I would rather not have to relearn all of my behaviours) I tried brace completion settings, but to no avail.

Also, this seems to be an issue with the new Razor editor -> switching to legacy made the issue go away.

Comment: Looks like there's a completion item that's not being shown yet is being committed. Consider opening an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/razor, the team is pretty responsive there.  Or file feedback through the VS IDE, it'll eventually get routed to them as well.

Comment: Does this happen only in the current project? I don't find any options to disable it. Have you created a new project to test it?